# Конвертировать в тип требуемый конструктором

Tags: c#

Можно ли конвертировать object в тип который требует конструктор класса явно не указывая тип для конвертации?

Сейчас я делаю так, но здесь нужно явно указать тип:

```
public static T ToType<T>(this object input){
    return (T)Convert.ChangeType(input, typeof(T));        
}
```

Comment: Думаю, что нельзя. Тогда бы потерялась безопасность типов.

Comment: Может вы что-то не так делаете? Возможно, вам проще реализовать интерфейс у типов и ничего не приводить?

Comment: Ну то есть это можно сделать через `dynamic`. Но скорее всего не нужно. Объясните лучше, зачем вам такое понадобилось, скорее всего есть более подходящее решение.

Comment: ...что вас не устраивает в варианте который сейчас есть?

Comment: Как вариант через рефлексию получить [типы параметров конструктора](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.parameterinfo.parametertype(v=vs.110).aspx) и подставлять в нужное место во время приведения.